# Can I access the random score of a document in a script_score function in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I do apply a `random_seed` to documents and need to make calculations based upon that score within a `script_score` function.

The random value needs to be sticky, hence I add a seed - therefore I use random_seed.

My requirements are:

- ignore the document score (I do that with `boost_mode` `replace`)
- the random value must be sticky, each user needs to see the same results (I do that with a per session seed)
- i need to access the random value within my `script_score` method or need to find out a way to create a sticky random value per document within the `script_score`

Comment: If you do have that random seed, why don't you pass that seed to your script, as well? (as a parameter) `"params": {
              "my_seed": 238
            }`

Comment: If i use that seed within the script, every document would get the same random value. I do not need the seed within the doc but the calculated random value.

Comment: Why do you need it? What are you trying to accomplish? You do have access to the current `_score` value in a `script_score`, is that not enough?

Comment: Since you use `replace` boost_mode your score is altered anyway, in the way you want it. So, accessing it in the `script_score` as `_score` should be close enough.

Comment: I've tested that and to me it looks like `_score` is the original document score, not the random_score.

Comment: Hm, can you share the complete query?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2KMYC9K - I found out that documents with less delivery_regions rank higher on average (if they match) than docs with more - and I assumed that this is due to the original score being weighted in.

Comment: I have experimented with that a bit and it looks like the _score get's always rounded to 1, which makes it essentially useless.

Comment: In your `script_score` you are doing `_score * something`. Do you want the random_score to be multiplied by a number?

Comment: No, i want to have it exponentially (the lower the exponent, the higher the final score, but guaranteed to be between 0 and 1)

Comment: I don't think you can access the random score in the script. Also, the [exp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_supported_decay_functions) decay function won't help you?

Comment: I'm not sure, I will have a look. Thank's for your help.